# Android studio gradle stuck at Fastutil.7.2.0.jar

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is the first time i installed android studio in my pc, but i have issue that the android studio is stuck at download fastutil-7.2.0.jar . Its been hour, but still not change. My pc also connect with internet. I already restart the software but still same. Help me with this. Help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think google gradle repo has an error now.

1. Open your project build.gradle
2. Add `mavenCentral()` to top of repositories

> build.gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```