# Android Studio can never download fastutil-7.2.0.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

Similar question: [Android studio gradle stuck at Fastutil.7.2.0.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301398/android-studio-gradle-stuck-at-fastutil-7-2-0-jar)

When I'm building my first Android App in Java, Android Studio 4.0 is always complaining:

```
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

However, it's possible to download the `jar` with the browser.

If I remove `jcenter()`in `build.gradle`, a similar error occurs:

```
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

This file doesn't even exist.

I tried modifying `build.gradle` or setting up proxy, but neither works.

`gradle.build` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

UPDATE:

Solved. Proxy's fault. Check `C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\gradle.properties`.

Comment: Post your build gradle file

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Updated. Thanks.

Comment: So you have `implementation group: 'it.unimi.dsi', name: 'fastutil', version: '7.2.0'` in your module app level build.gradle? It may be caused by proxy, check if your are under a proxy, if yes you should add the proxy settings in Android Studio.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I couldn't find "fastutil" in app/build.gradle. BTW, all configuration files are created by the IDE without modification.

Comment: Have you added the above dependency in your module app level build.gradle file or not? See how to add dependencies https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed Command line tools

if not install from
sdk manager > sdk tools > check command line tools and apply

Comment: This question seems to be out of date. Anyway, thanks for your answer!